# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client, NodeJs Error

Tags: node.js

I'm getting an error called "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". Here's my code

```
router.post('/patent', upload.array('patentFiles', 2), (req, res) => {
  var id = req.body.id
  var patentFile = req.files
  res.send(patentFile)

  Patent.findOne({ id: id }, (err, doc) => {
    if (doc) {
      res.status(404).send('Already Exists!')
    } else {
      var insertPatentRecord = new Patent({
        id: id
      })
      insertPatentRecord.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err)
        } else {
          res.send({
            msg: 'Saved',
            doc: doc
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Thank You very much

Comment: You have `res.send(patentFile)` and then again at after `find` query result. You cannot do that once response has been already sent.

Comment: Why are are you sending the `patentFile` back to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Once you send a response back to the client any further call to the response method will result in the "cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error. To avoid this, place `return` before the response call. Like so:

`return res.send(patentFile)`

However looking at the position of the response and seeing that you are also making a query to the Patent collection after it, you may want to change the position of the `res.send(patentFile)`.